# C# - How can I have a dynamic Image / BitmapSource accessible from XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, runtime

In my C# project I have a list of images which are resources compiled in the exe:

`/Pics/Image1.png
 /Pics/Image2.png
 /Pics/Image3.png
 ...`

In my code I process the images to match them to the theme of the application. The issue I am having is that I am trying to figure out an easy way to access these processed images in the XAML syntax.

This is how I typically access a resource image (pre-processed):

`<Image Source="/Pics/Image1.png" />`

So I would really like to access these processed images a similar way.

I tried a static dictionary like this:

`<Image Source="{x:Static local:Theme.Images.ImageDictionary[/Pics/Image1.png]}" />`

But this threw an error because it doesn't like the ".png", I haven't been able to get this working with dictionary keys. Not to mention this looks really ugly.

Ideally I would love to be able to "replace" the resource references, or create a resource at runtime (e.g. `PicsProcessed/Image1.png`) but haven't been able to figure a way to add or modify resources in a running C# application programmatically.

Any suggestions are really appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using a converter instead? You can still point it to the right image.

Comment: A converter seems like a very messy/complicated solution to the issue. I would like to see if there is another way that is easier to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a couple of days but I figured out a solution!

I moved all my images into another C# Project in the same solution, set to compile as a Class Libary DLL file called DynamicResources.dll (assembly name in the Project settings is "DynamicResources"). This project is added as a reference to the main project. As such I can access images in the XAML - clean and tidy:

```
<Image Source="/DynamicResources;component/pics/image1.png" />
```

Then in the post-build event for the main project, **I rename the compiled .dll so it doesn't get loaded by the main .exe binary at launch**:

```
copy "$(TargetDir)DynamicResources.dll" "$(TargetDir)DynamicResources.temp" 
del "$(TargetDir)DynamicResources.dll"
```

Then I used a third-party library called Mono.Cecil to load the DynamicResources.temp file (DLL format), replace the resources, write it back to memory, then tell the application to load it:

```
public static void UpdateAssembly()
{
    string dllFile = "DynamicResources.temp";
    string dllNamespace = "DynamicResources";

    var asm = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(dllFile);            
    var module = asm.Modules.FirstOrDefault();
    var resources = module.Resources;
    var dllResource = (EmbeddedResource)(resources.FirstOrDefault());
    var dllResourceReader = new ResourceReader(dllResource.GetResourceStream());
    var newResourceOutputStream = new MemoryStream();
    var newResourceWriter = new ResourceWriter(newResourceOutputStream);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry dllResourceEntry in dllResourceReader)
    {
       var image = (BitmapSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(dllResourceEntry.Value);

       Color foreground = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFFFF");
       var processed = (WriteableBitmap)ColorizeImage(image, foreground); // Your image processing function ?

       newResourceWriter.AddResource(dllResourceEntry.Key.ToString(), BitmapToByte(processed));       
    }
    newResourceWriter.Close();

    var newResource = new EmbeddedResource(dllResource.Name, dllResource.Attributes, newResourceOutputStream.ToArray());
    module.Resources.Remove(dllResource);
    module.Resources.Add(newResource);

    var woutput = new MemoryStream();

    asm.Write(woutput);
    var doutput = woutput.ToArray();
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(doutput);
}
public static MemoryStream BitmapToByte(BitmapSource bitmapSource)
{
    var encoder = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder();
    var frame = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource);
    encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    encoder.Save(stream);
    return stream;
}
public static void AttachAssembly(string myAsmFileName)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + myAsmFileName); // LoadFrom
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assembly.GetName());
}
```

**Important note: When iterating through resources, they become lowercase, so you must use lowercase file and folder names.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a `Bitmap` then setting it as the image `source`? I think this should be easy. Give your image a name, say `theImage`. You can't possibly reference the image without giving it a name.
Try the following:

```
string path="/Pics/Image3.png";//path to the image
var bitmapImage=new Bitmap(new Uri(path));
theImage.source=bitmapImage;//set the bitmap as the source.
```

There are other ways you can achieve this though. Hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. yes, I understand that I can set the source in the code behind as you show there. There are a lot of images scattered all throughout a large project that would need to be manually changed in the code behind, so this would take too long.

I have made a function to batch-process these image resources. I just need to figure out the best way of referencing this list of processed images from the XAML designer in the ".xaml" file, not from the C# code behind. Currently the images are stored in a `Dictionary<string, BitmapSource>` but can change this.